# Can a person be arrested/detained if a prohibited item is found in the carry-on luggage while transiting?

Tags: russia, prohibited-items, kazakhstan

Recently, while returning from St Petersburg to New Delhi via Almaty in Kazakhstan, our family had a rather bizarre experience. Before querying anything, I would like to sum up the situation -

**Event 1**

Our family of three checks-in at St Petersberg Pulkovo airport. At the last moment, we decided to take one of the checked-in baggage as a carry-on. While doing it, we forgot that the bag had a knife with 1-inch blade.

**Event 2**

The bag passes the screening at St Petersberg airport. We land in Almaty after 5 hours. During transiting, the knife is discovered in the bag and we are stopped. Normally when this happens, the officials just throw the prohibited items but the officials at the screening checkpoint decide to call the police.

**Event 3**

The police arrive and asks one of us to claim the bag. My mother claims it and her passport is taken by them. We start to worry a bit at this point. They return with a form titled “Protocol Exemption”. We sit with a Kazakh/Russian speaking policeman who fills the form in Russian. When my father expressed his concerns about what the form was about and what was being written on it, the policemen keeps repeating “ I am police ” and “ Law section 38 and 40 " with a stern look. Our requests for a translator are ignored. Finally, after being harassed and mystified for 15 minutes, we are let off after we sign the form.

Though I understand it was our fault of not checking the stuff in the bag before taking it as a carry on. I have few questions regarding the situation :-

1. Why wasn’t the knife taken out at Russian airport ? Is it because the officers failed to discover it or it is due to the fact that knives only larger than particular size are banned in carry-on baggage in Russia ?
2. As I had experienced before this trip, prohibited items in the baggage are often thrown. Were we made to sign only because we were in transit and had completed one part of journey with the knife in carry on baggage ?
3. Can carrying a prohibited item result in detention or arrest ? It would be great if anyone can explain this with respect to Kazakh law.
4. Was the policeman interested in taking bribe by intimidating us ?

**EDIT:**
Attached is the piece of paper issued to us after the matter got resolved.

[image: Image of Counterfoil of Protocol issued at Almaty Airport]

**EDIT 2:**

5. Will this incident result in extra scrutiny by the Kazakh officials or those from CIS countries if the passenger visits in future ? In other words, are such incidents kept in record books ?

Comment: "Was the policeman interested in taking bribe by intimidating us ?" - this might need to be removed because it's opinion based. My opinion is of course yes but then again I am biased.

Comment: Being in transit does not absolve you from your actions that violate the laws of the country in which you are transiting.  You are on their soil, in their airport, under their jurisdiction.  Being "in transit" simply means you can't leave the airport sterile area and enter any other part of that country.

Comment: "I am Police. Law Section 38 and 40" probably just means, "I barely speak a word of English so I don't understand what you're saying to me and I can't explain in any more detail." There's not a lot that he can do in that situation, if no translators are available.

Comment: Why wasn’t the knife taken out at Russian airport?
I once flew from Denver to Orlando with a Leatherman multi-tool with a 3" blade in my carry-on which was only discovered by security on my way back at Orlando international security check in.
This in a country pouring billions into DHS and in a constant state of panic about terrorism... what did you expect security would be like in Russia?

Comment: I'm kind of surprised no one is trying to explain what the "Law section 38 and 40" means. Surely, this refers to some specific statute.

Comment: @jpmc26 I tried to look these up, but unfortunately this isn't enough to go on. Nothing by these numbers in the customs code seems relevant, and civil code is just too large to go through all the sections #38 and #40 in each article of each chapter.

Comment: I'm missing the part of the story where anyone was arrested? And because each country has sovreign power over admitting non-citizens, I suspect they can pretty much detain anyone they want. Especially those who violate laws or airport security protocols.

Comment: @DeanKuga Yeah, I've accidentally taken a knife through TSA at least 3 times. They never caught it. Granted, it wasn't as large as a Leatherman multi-tool. I think the most concerning miss I've heard about, though, was when a soldier who had been in the special forces in Afghanistan accidentally brought **C-4** through TSA, in his carry-on. They only caught it on his return trip.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

> Why wasn’t the knife taken out at Russian airport ?

Probably because they missed it during screening. Airport security [has been known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slovak_Police_training_explosives_incident) to miss actual explosives in peoples bags, so a tiny knife is not a particular surprise.

> Were we made to sign only because we were in transit

You were forced to sign a paper because Kazakhstan and the surrounding countries are extremely bureaucratic and probably require some sort of paperwork to remove forbidden items from passengers.

> Can carrying a prohibited item result in detention or arrest ?

Of course it can, especially if you're [carrying something illegal like drugs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Tuong_Nguyen). However a small knife is extremely unlikely to bring any sort of trouble.

> Was the policeman interested in taking bribe by intimidating us ?

Policemen aren't known for their friendly demeanor in that region. Just because someone talks to you impolitely doesn't mean they're asking for a bribe. It's quite unlikely that someone would demand a bribe in plain sight at an international airport, especially for such a minor offense.

Comment: +1 The paperwork may be an anti-corruption move so that they can't easily just steal things from passengers by claiming they are forbidden.

Answer (score 18):

1. Either the knife was not noticed, or the blade was considered short enough to pass under Russian rules. This is irrelevant though: just because I can legally bring an apple through security in Singapore doesn't mean Customs is obliged to let it through in Australia.
2. The consequences of having prohibited items depends on local law and the discretion of the screeners. Being in transit is irrelevant.
3. Absolutely: even in transit, you are subject to Kazakh law.  For example, Singapore regularly executes drug smugglers caught in transit.
4. Possibly, although if so, I would have expected them to hint at this. Bribery is also difficult if there are multiple officers and security cameras etc involved, which would be the case at an airport.
5. Highly unlikely.  The confiscation was carried out by airport security, you were not arrested or charged with a crime.

Comment: Do you have a citation for the claim that the TSA allows blades, like knives? The only mention I was able to see was an allowance for scissors (not knives), shorter than 4 inches.

Comment: @EthanKaminski The "sharp objects" section of the TSA's [What can I bring?](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring) page agrees with you. As I recall, there was some discussion of relaxing the rules amount small knives (e.g., penknives) a few years ago, possibly resulting in different agencies having different policies (e.g., the FAA being OK with small knives but the TSA not, or the TSA being OK with them but somebody higher up saying no).

Comment: @EthanKaminski D'oh, you're right, looks like proposed changes in 2013 to allow knifes were cancelled.  Edited answer accordingly.

Comment: Singapore **regularly** executes drug smugglers in transit?  Why would any smuggler **transit** in a place like Singapore anyway??

Comment: @LorenPechtel Maybe people taping packs of drugs to their thighs and transiting through airport security aren't the brightest bulbs in the box in the first place.  Ignorance isn't much of an excuse though, since the Singapore immigration arrival card has a nice warning in bold red letters about death for drug traffickers: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/89/ImmigrationCard-Singapore-DeathPenalty-20051226.jpg

Comment: @DavidRicherby TSA and FAA were actually ok with it. It was the flight attendants' union that complained and got the proposed rule cancelled. TSA wanted the change because they were (and are) wasting way too much of their time dealing with small knives that don't actually pose a threat in a post-9/11 world rather than looking for actual threats.

Comment: @jpatokal As a Singaporean, I've always wondered what exactly the drug mule was supposed to do *at that point*. Sure, we not only put that language in bold red in our immigration arrival card, we also mention it in our "Welcome to Singapore video"- but my question is: once in the plane, what exactly is a drug carrier with cold feet supposed to do? Throw himself at the mercy of the crew (and then the authorities) - noting that SG is not known for its clemency? Or just stash the drugs in the plane toilet? I really think there should be a "surrender contraband without legal consequence" option.

Comment: @Deepak *That* problem is solvable, just stuff them in the trash.  (And FWIW, many airports do have amnesty bins for contraband, although this usually means leftover fruit, not drugs.)  The bigger problem is that if you come home without the drugs, the people who wanted them will be *very, very* unhappy with you...

Comment: @jpatokal To be frank, I was not aware of any "amnesty bins" in my country's single international airport. As for the "bigger problem", the really sad part is that the drug lords often hold the families of the mules hostage.

Answer (score 9):

While I certainly understand your concerns about signing something you don't understand, in this particular case it's nothing to worry about.

Obviously, full name of the passenger, flight number, details and signature of the person who made [sic] the protocol are obvious.  The parts in Russian say:

> Flight number 907 *on the route* **Deli**
>   Found and seized **knife 1 item (KNIFE)**

Now, to answer your questions...

> Why wasn’t the knife taken out at Russian airport ?

Most likely, security just missed it.  You yourself said that it was a small knife - the security person in Pulkovo could have been tired or for any other reason missed it - that's all to it.

> Were we made to sign only because we were in transit and had completed one part of journey with the knife in carry on baggage?

This had nothing to do with transit. You were required to sign a piece of paper confirming that an item was seized.  If you didn't sign it, you could then claim that this item was stolen by security personnel or what not.  This way, there is a proof - both for you and the airport personnel that a prohibited item was seized from you.

> Can carrying a prohibited item result in detention or arrest?

It certainly could.  Note that while in any airport, you are within the Jurisdiction of the country where the airport is located. Now, if *restricted* means *illegal in the country*, then absolutely, you can (and most likely will be) arrested, charged with possession of illegal items - and the police/courts would take it from there.  If on the other hand it means *prohibited in hand luggage but otherwise legal*, then very unlikely.

> Was the policeman interested in taking bribe by intimidating us?

Extremely unlikely.  The more likely scenario was that he was just annoyed that you were wasting his time, as he was simply following a standard protocol, dealing with something probably boring (in his police view, maybe) and wanted to be done with this.

Answer (score 4):

If they wanted a bribe, they would typically say you have to pay a fine. Then you would discover that actually paying the fine requires you to do something that is incompatible with your journey (like obtaining a form from the bank, which would make you miss your next flight). Of course, they would offer you an already filled form right in the airport, but you'd have to pay in cash and get no receipt.

Your incident doesn't look like an attempt to get a bribe, the airport officials were simply annoyed that they had to spend time on these forms, which would explain the rudeness. They also refused to call you an interpreter since they decided you didn't need one for a simple item seizure protocol.

Unfortunately, you weren't told sections 38 and 40 of *which law* were applied to you, so it's hard to say what repercussions the incident may have on your future trips. Considering your knife was simply seized and no fine or court presence was due, I would hazard a guess that there will be none.

Comment: There is a clue in the image attached by OP - "Protocol No 540". A Google search of this, with some other keywords got me to this: http://www.gratanet.com/up_files/AV17_Chapter-14_Kazakhstan.pdf which suggests the travelers were detained for *"breach by the passenger of the Passenger Transportation
Rules and/or actions of the passenger that may influence the
safety of the flight;"* (see page 101). Could not find any reference to "section 38 and 40", but it seems like *Kazakhstan "Air Transportation Rules"* refers to a larger document, that I was unable to find.

Comment: @CactusCake That document seems to specify when a passenger can be denied boarding, not sure if it's related to the OP's case.